# How to use context.log from in separate modules

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

Each of the functions in a node.js function app receive the context object and I can use context.log to write to App Insights. However, this context object is not available in helper modules within my project.

Other than passing the context object to every method, is there any other way to access context.log across the project?

Right now, I'm using console.log, but that means the operation_id is not populated in App Insights for these entries. The developer guide from Microsoft also advises not to use console.log

I've come across third party NPM packages that cater for this scenario, but I'd like to avoid using them if possible, particularly if there is an out-of-the-box way of achieving this.

Comment: I know you don't want external library but I have seen this library https://github.com/BrianRosamilia/azure-function-log-intercept    it just mask the context.log under the console.log so that you can use the console.log everywhere

Answer (score 0):

- I know you don't want to use external library but `azure-function-log-intercept`  is an external library where it simply masks the `context.log` under `console.log` . So that we can use `console.log` like a `context.log`  without passing the `context`, also this library doesn't have any external dependency.
- Just add the following code before logging

```
intercept(context);
```

Here is my function:

```
var  test = require('./test');
const  intercept = require('azure-function-log-intercept');
module.exports = async  function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    console.log("Console logging with out context");
    context.log("original logging");
    intercept(context);
    test()
    const  responseMessage = "Azure Functions"
    context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body:  responseMessage
    };
}
```

my test module:

```
function  test()
{
    console.log("hello");
}
module.exports = test;
```

[image]

Refer this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/BrianRosamilia/azure-function-log-intercept) of azure-function-log-intercept  for it's implementation.